# Is there a word like "unary" meaning "consisting of *more than one* element"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

*Unary* means "consisting of one element"; is there a word meaning "consisting of *more than one* element"?

*Poly-ary* sounds wrong, as does *mult-ary...*

What is the opposite (in this sense) of *unary*?

Comment: Simply "non-unary"? http://ai.stanford.edu/~koller/Papers/Grove+al:96a.pdf

Comment: @Yee-Lum: But *non-unary* allows for *nullary* (*niladic*) also. The OP apparently wants n-ary where *n* > 1.

Comment: That's true. The title and body seem to be asking slightly different questions, in that case.

Comment: @Yee-lum I don't think opposite has such a concrete definition, so I clarified exactly which opposite I meant in the body.

Comment: "Plurality" technically fits, but has acquired conflicting meanings over the ages.

Answer (score 2):

The word *plurarity* does not appear in the dictionary, but if you google it there are quite a few cases of it being used this way.

While *plur-* is a valid Latin prefix, English words using it usually start with *plural-,* *pluralism* for instance.

So I suppose it could be seen as a portmanteau of *plural* and *arity.*

In that same sense, a word for n-arity > 1, could be *plurary.*

Comment: This is a noun, not an adjective, though for that matter, I'm pretty sure simple _plural_ fits the bill.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The word I'm recommending is plurary.  See the last sentence.

Comment: Let's just hope the rural juror never has to use that word

Comment: @SamWashburn I missed that detail.  It's a horrible word, but plurality is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *multiple-arity* if different numbers of arguments are accepted (e.g. a polymorphic function/method), or *n-ary* if you want to be indefinite about the arity.  But I don't know of a term for arity > 1.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity